# Role of hcl gas in organic reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

I encountered many questions in the competitive exam field of high school organic chemistry where we add some compounds and treat it in excess alcohol solutions in the presence of dry hcl gas, it is obvious how the mechanisms might go if the hcl is in liquid solution but when i see dry hcl gas i have no idea how it might influence the reactions. 
From what i can tell it is used to signify that the expected mechanism we are targeting is not common as there is this gas component present but how exactly does the presence of this acidic gas influence the mechanisms of the reactions? [image]

Comment: And what you'd expect when you wouldn't expect that to be a catch?

Comment: Well the hplus would activate the carbonyl carbon even more amd the alcohol will attack and deprotonate to give product in the option a but this wont happen in dry hcl as hcl needs moisture to ionize

Comment: That's not true. While in vapor phase HCl won't protonate anything, but it's only a way to deliver it to the reaction mixture. Anhydrous mixture lowers acidity but not much.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing about HCl gas in these reactions is that it is dry, there is no water present ruling out any hydrolytic pathways. This means that the first step to consider is a protonation by HCl as HCl can ionise in alcoholic solvent, followed by nucleophilic attack by the alcohol solvent. In the example shown the oxygen of the carbonyl is protonated and MeOH attacks. The transient product is the hemiacetal A, this is then protonated, water leaves stabilised by electron donation from the OMe group, a second MeOH adds to give B as the final product. Further reading and a diagram of the mechanism is [here](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/Carey5th/Ch17/ch17-3-4-2.html)

Comment: But how that protonation happen without moist hcl in solution and if there is no role of hcl why is it even present we can very well remove it from our catalyst

Comment: HCl can ionise in protic solvents. You need something to protonate the carbonyl group. TFA or Methanesulfonic acid will do as well. Dry HCl in MeOH/EtOH can be generated by adding Acetyl chloride or Me3SiCl to the anhydrous alcohol.

Comment: While we appreciate your contribution to the site, it would be preferable to not answer questions, that do not comply with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/).